# How many threads are used in mule when moving across request-response inbound-endpoints?

Tags: mule

I am trying to undersand the threading model used in Mule. Mule docs quote:

> If you are using synchronous processing, the same thread will be used
>   to carry the message all the way through Mule

So if I recieve a message on a HTTP request-response inbound endoint and then send it to another inbound-endpoint, say a vm inbound enpoint using request-response. Is this 1 thread being used or 2 threads being used? 1 from he HTTP connector pool and 1 from the VM pool?

Example:

```
<flow>

<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="xxx" />

<vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"address="vm://zzz" />
</flow>

<flow>
  <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"address="vm://zzz" />

...
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the inbound endpoints use request-response then the same thread is used across all flows. You can check this out in console output. In your case you'll have an output like

```
-- Flow1
[[threadtest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: /
[[threadtest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1269236931'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
[[threadtest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1269236931'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
-- Flow2
[[threadtest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: /
```

where `[[threadtest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]` is the name of the thread used to process the message